# Access to purchased movies on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, itunes

Is it possible to access movies which were purchased via iTunes in an app?  I know there's some iPod integration functionality possible - pick from iPod - is there a way to do this with videos as well?  Which frameworks would provide this?

Furthermore, I would like the ability to set an in and out point, add a sound file on top, and then export the video for uploading to Youtube/etc.  With the video from iTunes, would this be possible?

This is just for a tech demonstration, not a published app, so I'm not worried about the licensing side of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get access to films purchased via iTunes, they're protected by DRM, but you *can* get access to purchased film clips.

Have a look at the MediaPlayer framework. There's `MPMediaQuery` for querying the iTunes database and `MPMediaPickerController` which looks like it *should* let you pick films but only seems to work with songs. It's a moot point seeing as you can't do anything interesting with films it could pick if it only worked.

If it's just a demo, why not stick some non DRMed movies in your Documents folder and open the from there?